# Liferay bug? Styles with child combinator is wrongly interpreted

Tags: html, css, liferay

If I enter advanced styling like follows

```
tr > td
{
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

it turns into following source code

```
<style type="text/css">tr &gt;td{padding-bottom:50px;}</style>
```

i.e. greater sign it escaped and ignored by browser.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a bug. I've filed [LPS-42779](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42779)